# SageMaker: AccessDeniedException ClientError when calling CreateModel

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-policies

ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateModel operation: User: arn:aws:sts::0123456789:assumed-role/sagemakeraccesstoservices/SageMaker is not authorized to perform: sagemaker:CreateModel on resource: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-2:0123456789:model/blazingtext-2022-08-09-13-58-21-739 because no identity-based policy allows the sagemaker:CreateModel action

I made the following policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sagemaker:*",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, it still doesn't work.
Any pointers?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this [Access Policy page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html) for best practises